# Shiny server-side updateSelectizeInput does not create selection list

Tags: shiny, selectize.js

The following code produces an empty selection box whereas I expected a list of state abbreviation + name pairs.

```
updateSelectizeInput(session, 'selectizer',
                       server=TRUE,
                       label=NULL,
                       choices = cbind(abb=state.abb, name=state.name),
                       options = list(render = I(
                        '{
                         option: function(item, escape) {
                            return "<div>" + escape(item.abb) + " " + 
                            escape(item.name) + "</div>";
                          }
                        }'), maxItems=3, placeholder='Select a state')
                      )
```

This code does what I expect:

```
updateSelectizeInput(session, 'basic_selectizer',
                       server=TRUE,
                       label=NULL,
                       choices=paste(state.abb,state.name),
                       options=list(maxItems=3, placeholder='Select a state')
                      )
```

I would like to get the full power of render but can't seem to make it work.  What am I doing wrong with the render version?

Comment: I asked a followUp question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523881/updateselectizeinput-behaves-strange

Comment: Take a look here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/SCLzc8nKotM