# UpdateSelectizeInput behaves strange

Tags: r, shiny

This is probably very similar to the following question:

[Shiny server-side updateSelectizeInput does not create selection list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38149266/shiny-server-side-updateselectizeinput-does-not-create-selection-list)

I have created an MWE so that you can better monitor the problem. This MWE ist basically taken from shiny: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selectize.html, but it does not produce the expected outcome.

```
library(shiny)

# ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
      selectizeInput('foo', label = NULL, choices = NULL, options = list(
        placeholder = 'Select something...')
    )
  )
)


# server
server <- function(input, output,session) {


  # update the render function for selectize
  updateSelectizeInput(session,
                       'foo',
                       choices = cbind(name = rownames(mtcars), mtcars),
                       server=T,
                       options = list(render = I(
                         '{
    option: function(item, escape) {
      return "<div><strong>" + escape(item.name) + "</strong> (" +
             "MPG: " + item.mpg +
             ", Transmission: " + item.am == 1 ? "automatic" : "manual" + ")"
    }
          }'))
  )

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I really have no idea what's wrong here and am grateful for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/SCLzc8nKotM

I have to specify search, label and valueField in order to make selectize work.